# repeat break columns in a single query group report oracle

Tags: oracle, report

From the oracle reports tutorial,

http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B10602_01/orbr_grpl_single.htm

I have a requirement that is similar to the above report but would have the department id column to repeat each time instead of just once as above. So I tried following the steps and then moved the repeating frame of non-grouped fields over to the grouped field(Department Id in the tutorial ex above) to get repetition. But I am getting an error "has an illegal print condition". Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a matter of having a copy of the department_id column in the "detail" group of the report and displaying that one rather than the "master" group copy, like this:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,
       JOB_ID, SALARY, DEPARTMENT_ID, 
       DEPARTMENT_ID AS DEPARTMENT_ID2 -- Second copy
FROM EMPLOYEES 
ORDER BY DEPARTMENT_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID
```

### Level1 Group

- DEPARTMENT_ID (not displayed)

### Level2 Group

- DEPARTMENT_ID2 (displayed)
- JOB_ID
- EMPLOYEE_ID
- ...

**EDIT**: Having just tried this, I found that I did have to initially display both DEPARTMENT_IDs to make the wizard work.  However, once the report was created I could then manually delete the first DEPARTMENT_ID field in the layout editor to achieve the desired result.

Comment: I have done so but when I move the repeating frame over the DEPARTMENT_ID field and run the report, it throws "has an illegal print condition" error.

Comment: Don't do that.  I didn't move any frames at all, there is no need to.